# Boomi to SFDC REST API with OAuth 2.0: 400 Bad Request

Tags: rest-api, integration

Use case:

1. Boomi configured to use HTTP Client connector as per Boomi [configuration doc](https://community.boomi.com/docs/DOC-2551)
2. Connected App setup in SFDC as per instructions above
3. OAuth Token successfully generated
4. Boomi POST to SFDC `/services/data/v43.0/sobjects/SomePlatformEvent__e` with a correct JSON body

**Result**: `400 Bad Request`

```
Unable to browse connector: invalid response:
[{"errorCode":"URL_NOT_RESET","message":"Destination URL not reset. 
The URL returned from login must be set"}]
```

If the OAuth token acquisition is successful, that indicates successful authentication so why would the POST of the sobject fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*It took us 2 hours to figure this out and is basically a faceplant. Posting as answer to save the next person this issue as we didn't see a similar solution elsewhere*

The [Boomi instructions](https://community.boomi.com/docs/DOC-2551) are quite clear yet in a spasm of epistemic arrogance, we refused to believe them

### We had:

[image]

This is WRONG. `Instance url` means `Instance Url` Per the instructions 
["In AtomSphere create a new HTTP Connection"](https://community.boomi.com/docs/DOC-2551).

> URL = Base URL of your Salesforce org's REST API. Salesforce instance
>   (e.g. na7) and version (e.g. v39.0) may differ. For example,
>   https://na7.salesforce.com/services/data/v39.0/. Remember the
>   remainder of the API endpoint will be configured in the Operation
>   component.

### You need to have:

[image]

where `na30` happened to be our pod; yours may be different.

Although the Boomi doc says it uses the [SFDC OAuth web server flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.196.0.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_web_server_oauth_flow.htm), and that flow says that SFDC will return the instanceURL as per:

```
{"id":"https://login.salesforce.com/id/00Dx0000000BV7z/005x00000012Q9P",
"issued_at":"1278448101416",
"refresh_token":"5Aep8614iLM.Dq661ePDmPEgaAW9Oh_L3JKkDpB4xReb54_
pZebnUG0h6Sb4KUVDpNtWEofWM39yg==",
"instance_url":"https://na30.salesforce.com",
"signature":"CMJ4l+CCaPQiKjoOEwEig9H4wqhpuLSk4J2urAe+fVg=",
"access_token":"00Dx0000000BV7z!AR8AQP0jITN80ESEsj5EbaZTFG0R
NBaT1cyWk7TrqoDjoNIWQ2ME_sTZzBjfmOE6zMHq6y8PIW4eWze9JksNEkWUl.Cju7m4"}
```

Boomi seems to ignore this and requires manual specification of the instance URL. As such, *if your pod changes*, your Boomi connection will break unless you coordinate the change.